# Add always visible NEW button to related list

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, related-list, relatedlistnew

I created a custom object, that is related to my Opportunities, and I would like to offer the possibility to create a new record of this custom object, but achieve this with the fewest clicks possible.

I'm in lightning experience, so I added a related list to my Opportunity Page Layout. There I can see that there's a small arrow, which if I click, there's a **New** button where users can create records.

Is it possible, to bring this NEW button more forward?

Any way to have a NEW button somewhere more visible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have that related list component in a sidebar column on the layout.  Move it to a wider column and the button will display without an arrow that you have to click.